# Showing content when ID meets a value of 10 or above

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to show a 'Show Past Blogs' Link but only when the blog hits 11 and above blog ID inserts. So up to 10 it has to be hidden from the users view as its not necessary to have it on show and anything after 10 for it to show for users to find the older blogs created.

I have tried the below, with no prevail.

```
$blogids = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT blogitem_id FROM blogdata") or die("SELECT Error: ".mysqli_error($mysqli));
$blogs = mysqli_num_rows($blogids);

if($blogs==10) {
echo'<div class = "blog_show_posts" onclick = "blog_stream_count+=10;blog_stream_load();"> Show Past Blogs </div></div>';
}else{ echo""; }?>
```

Comment: What does the value of `$blogs` show?  You're currently doing a comparison of `$blogs == 10`.  If you want it to happen when there are more than 10, you should use `$blogs > 10`;

Comment: Your code will work when the quantity of posts is exactly 10. You might want to change it to `if ( $blogs >= 10 ) { ... }`

Comment: Oh of course. Greater than ten not comparison. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Thank you guys. The solution was just adding a simple > instead of == Thank you to you both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$blogs==10`
Will only show when count is exactly 10.
try
`$blogs > 10`

Comment: I can not yet accept the answer due to rep. But its correct. My simple error that I should have noticed. Cheers